# Ask a question on maximization lemma in matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis
Book by Dean W. Wichern and Richard A. Johnson, chapter 3 section 3.7 talks about maximization lemma. It says Let **B** (pxp) be positive definite and **d** (px1) be a given vector. Then, for an arbitrary nonzero vector **x** (px1),

$$max \frac{x'd}{x'Bx} = d'B^{-1}d$$

with the maximum attained when $x = cB^{-1}d$ for any constant c not zero.

My question: I can understand the proof. But when I plug in    $x = cB^{-1}d$, what I get is $d (B^{-1})'d$, which is different from $d B^{-1}d$.

Comment: For $B$ positive definite, $B^{-1}$ is positive definite as well, such that ${B^{-1}}'=B^{-1}$ (I assume $'$ is the transpose operation).
However, the term you're maximizing does not seem to be bounded, as you could take $x = \lambda d$ which would make $\frac{1}{\lambda}\frac{d'd}{d'Bd}$ converge to infinity when $\lambda$ goes to $0$.

Comment: No, it is bounded by the extended Cauchy-Sachwarz inequality. The important fact is B is positive definite.  $B^{-1}$ is also positive definite. And all positive definite matricies are symmetric. That's why its transpose is itself.